Rigging a mermaid results in Rigify error: Cannot connect to non-chain parent rig. Incorrect armature for type "chain_rig"
I'm brand new to rigging and just want to rig this mermaid simple enough to pose and render. I thought using the Rigify basic human armature and then deleting the bottom half and adding a couple bones to substitute it should work fine.
But I kept getting this error when trying to generate it. I keep seeing a similar error but about disjointed bones or something, but I don't know if mine falls under that.
If you have an answer, can you be as detailed as you can?



The bone hierarchy doesn't look right to me. The tail bones (ex-legs) should be children of the hip bone (spine.001?). But in your rig, the tail is the parent of the other bones. You can see this in the outliner. Also note that Rigify uses so-called Rig Types to define body parts (e.g. tail, leg, arm, hand, face, etc). If you have added the tail bones you need to define the Rig Type for the first bone of the chain (Pose Mode > Bone properties). Otherwise, Rigify won't create control bones for the tail.

The Rigify error is due to the fact that you have deleted the root bone "spine" and the spine bone chain (spine.001 to spine.004) now has no Rig Type. The Rig Type is normally always defined for the first bone in the chain.
The solution is simple. Just define the correct Rig Type for the first spine bone of the chain. Then add a tail bone chain and give it also a Rig Type, maybe spines.basic_tail. This type of tail can bend forwards and backwards, but not to the side.
1. You want to fix some other issues:

your mesh has flipped normals. This leads to a strange deformation as described in your other question my mesh is warping a bunch after rigging
your model is rotated by 90° around the Z-axis, so the menu View > Viewpoint > Front (Numpad 1) shows the left side, and
View > Viewpoint > Right (Numpad 3) shows the front, and so on. Due to the incorrect orientation, you cannot use the mirroring for the bones, as there is only one X-mirroring (left <-> right).Rotate the model (body, eyes and head) and the metarig by -90° around the Z-axis. Apply Ctrl+A > Rotation for all objects. Also, apply the Scale for the metarig.
make sure the model parts and the metarig is centered along the X-axis (x=0.0) and move it up a bit along the (Z-axis) so it stands on the "ground" (XY-plane). You can enter the value in the side panel to fix it.
fix the eyes. Apply the Mirror modifier for the eyes because of the wrong rotation, and the modifier doesn't work with Rigify anyway. It makes her cross-eyed.


2. Fix the Metarig for the Mermaid

the rib cage is not deformed. Make sure that it is covered by a single large spinal bone. The abdomen, on the other hand, can be curved, which is why it needs at least two, better three, small spinal bone.
I would also add back the deleted hip/pelvis bones, as these add volume to the hips and butt. You can duplicate & separate them from a new metarig, then join them with your metarig. Don't forget to rename them (pelvis.R and pelvis.L)
make sure the bone hierarchy is correct. Check a new metarig if you are unsure. The first spine bone must be the parent for the spine chain. It's also the parent of the hip bones and the tail (keep offset, not connected).
make the tail a connected chain bone (no keep offset). Make sure you bone roll is correct (0°) so the tail can bend to the front and the back. The roll value is in the side panel if you select the bone.

If you're happy with the bone layout, switch to Pose mode and define the Rig Types:

spines.basic_spine for the first spine bone
spines.basic_tail for the first tail bone

Finally make sure, the mesh objects only have 1 Armature modifier and the Subdivision Surface modifier is at the bottom of the stack.

Final notes
For a better deformation of the elbows and wrists you can add a few more loop cuts. They are a bit too low-poly to bend nicely.
In contrast the head is fairly high-poly. I guess you did this for the mouth and lips. You can bake a normal map. Then you probably don't need another level 2 Subdivision Surface modifier that generates a lot more geometry to get the same result. Just an idea to consider.
Here is the blend file with the changes for your exercises ;-)
 
(Blender 3.5, compressed)

Ooops! I just noticed that I've messed up the center line and seams on her back. You have to merge some vertices and mark the seam properly.
